# Evaluating 1/(1+2) + 1/(1+2+3) + 1/(1+2+3+4)... + 1/(1+2+3+4...+100)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fractions

Evaluate 1/(1+2) + 1/(1+2+3) + 1/(1+2+3+4)... + 1/(1+2+3+4...+100)

This is a math competition question that I have tried solving for a long time as I can't use a calculator. What is the simplest way of solving this question without using a calculator?

Comment: Hint: There is a formula for the sum of the fist $n$ natural numbers : )

Comment: Fins the first few sums, and see if there is a pattern

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac1{\sum_{r=1}^nr}=\dfrac2{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{2(n+1-n)}{n(n+1)}=f(n)-f(n+1)$$ where $f(r)=\dfrac2r$

Use [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)